# How to Find All Users Affiliated with A Permission Set License?

Tags: permission-sets, licenses

How do i find all users affiliated with a permission set license?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm going to roll back the edit, because answers should be answers and not in the questions :) I can see you accepted Hermant's answer which is perfect, but if you want to post this info too it should be as another answer. Thanks for participating :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this, using the objects `PermissionSetLicenseAssign` and `PermissionSetLicense`.

You can try with below `SOQL`

```
SELECT PermissionSetLicense.DeveloperName, PermissionSetLicense.MasterLabel, Assignee.Name FROM PermissionSetLicenseAssign WHERE PermissionSetLicense.MasterLabel= 'yourpermissionsetlicencelabel'
```

See if this helps!

Comment: Dude You're awesome, tyvm!